# jqgrid no rows in Edge browser

Tags: jqgrid

I have a page where I use free jqGrid 4.14.0 and use serializeGridData with a SOAP request. In IE 11 everything is fine but in Edge the grid has no rows only the header is shown. I debugged the page and can see that the SOAP request and response are alright. Can anybody give a hint how I can find out the problem or what should be a workaround for this. Thanx.

Comment: Could you prepare the demo, which can be used to reproduce the problem? You should include SOAP response, which you get from the server. The response can be loaded from the Echo service (or from the text file) to simulate the problem. For example, the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zqLp4yrg/43/ uses `url: "/echo/json/", postData: {json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse)},mtype: "POST",datatype: "json"`. One can uses `url: /echo/xml/` and `postData: { xml: soapResponseAsString },mtype: "POST",datatype:"xml"` (see [here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)) to load XML data from Echo service.

Comment: Here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/psturm/rugr8tc0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML data, which you need to parse contains namespace. You used escaped strings like `"rs\\:data"` and `"z\\:row"` to parse the data.

```js
xmlReader: {
    root: "rs\\:data",
    row: "z\\:row",
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "[ows_ID]"
}
```

in your demo https://jsfiddle.net/psturm/rugr8tc0/. Such way isn't safe it depends on the version oh jQuery, which you use and from web browser, which you use. I recommend you to use own callback function, which get the required XML nodes. For example, you can use

```js
xmlReader: {
    root: function (node) {
        //return node.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild;
        return getChildNodesByName(
            node.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild,
            "rs:data")[0];
    },
    row: function (node) {
        return getChildNodesByName(node, "z:row");
    },
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "[ows_ID]"
}
```

where the function `getChildNodesByName` is

```js
function getChildNodesByName (node, name) {
    var items = [], children = node.childNodes, iChild, nChildren = children.length;
    for (iChild = 0; iChild < nChildren; iChild++) {
        child = children[iChild];
        if (child.nodeType === 1 && child.nodeName === name) {
            items.push(child);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

The resulting demo seems to work in all web browsers which are installed on my computer. See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/rugr8tc0/7/